# Unable to connect to local host from 127.0.0.1, localhost and not even with my public ip

Tags: iis, localhost, ip, iis-express, netstat

I have my Windows server 2012 which is active on production and running 2 websites of .NET. Now I want to run my wordpress site I had configured everything and my wordpress site was working fine before but all of sudden now am unable to connect to local host and even wp admin dashboard is not appearing so I deleted all that stuff uninstalled MYSQL connector MYSQL and web platform installer too. Even now I'm facing the same problem.
Whenever I try to connect 127.0.0.1 /Localhost I get the same message for both "This site can't be
reached" and if I try to connect with my public ip it says "HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found."

My `netstat` results are mentioned below:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>netsh http show iplisten
```

### IP addresses present in the IP listen list:

```
173.208.205.34
173.208.205.35
173.208.205.36

C:\Users\Administrator>netstat -ano

Active Connections

 

 1. Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State          
    PID   TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              
    LISTENING
    1192   TCP    0.0.0.0:180            0.0.0.0:0             
    LISTENING       1388   TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0      
    LISTENING       4   TCP    0.0.0.0:1433           0.0.0.0:0         
    LISTENING       2812   TCP    0.0.0.0:1443           0.0.0.0:0      
    LISTENING       1388   TCP    173.208.205.34:80      0.0.0.0:0      
    LISTENING       4   TCP    173.208.205.34:139     0.0.0.0:0         
    LISTENING       4   TCP    173.208.205.34:443     0.0.0.0:0         
    LISTENING       4   TCP    173.208.205.34:443    
    160.153.147.141:35160  TIME_WAIT       0  
 TCP    173.208.205.34:1433    122.176.28.110:2048    ESTABLISHED     28
```

Additionally, I have checked the etc/hosts file it have 127.0.0.1 localhost uncommented there.
I have also disabled the firewall that make no change.

Can anyone tell what is wrong with this ?

Comment: check on IIS manager to see if site has stopped. Right click site name and start

Comment: @LinkedListT Thanks for responding but my website is running already! but am still facing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that there is no 0.0.0.0:80 in the IP listen list. Does your site bind to localhost:80?

The correct IP address in list should include

```
    0.0.0.0:80 (ipv4)   and    [::]:80   (ipv6)
```

I think you can add 127.0.0.1 to IP listen list.

```
netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=127.0.0.1
```

Then check whether it is in list.
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Bruce. Yes, you are right i had also figured this out and also added the 127.0.0.1 in the listen list but now when I type Localhost it works fine and if I search my Public ip or 127.0.0.1 on the browser I get a blank page with a message "Not Found
HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found."

Comment: I think the request has been sent to IIS because it returned a 404 instead of a connection refused.You can check the record of this request in the IIS log, what is the requested url, and what is the sub-status code of 404. It is also recommended that you restart the w3svc service.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion dude! Sadly it didn't worked for me but I figured another way for hosting my website through Linux hosting.